Grafana label value to numeric value for graphs
sensorReading{instance="192.168.xxx.xxx", officeSensorNumber="1"} which returns
{__name__="sensorReading", instance="192.168.xxx.xxx", job="IPMI", officeSensorNumber="1", sensorReading="43.000"}
{__name__="sensorReading", instance="192.168.xxx.xxx", job="IPMI", officeSensorNumber="1", sensorReading="44.000"}
{__name__="sensorReading", instance="192.168.xxx.xxx", job="IPMI", officeSensorNumber="1", sensorReading="45.000"}

and all of the returns have value of 1.
How can I take the value from sensorReading and use it in time series graph as a value which will create graphs?
Currently I have one line with different color dots. And each color represents the value of sensorReading

AFAIK, you can not. This is an incorrect (logically, not technically) exposition format, and Grafana can't convert it.

@markalex any suggestions how can i achieve the result that i want?

Fix exporter to give data in a proper format: with value in value, not label.

@markalex i try to change sensorReading to gauge but it did not help :/

What I meant is for exposition format to have real value, like sensorReading{instance="192.168.xxx.xxx", job="IPMI", officeSensorNumber="1"} 45.0. Not a word was spoken about type of metric.

@markalex can you please share how to fix the exporter or any kind of resource where i can read how to fix the exporter.

How do you expect anybody to help you with fixing exporter, if we know nothing of your exporter? Here's general recommendations on how exporters supposed to be developed. And here's reference for exposition format.
